# How do I apply a css class to certain elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a CSS-class `RoundedActivityCell` in my stylesheet, like this:

```
.RoundedActivityCell {
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; /* rounds corners for firefox */ 
    border-radius:4px 4px 4px 4px; /* rounds corners for other browsers */
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 18px;
    width: 150px; /* Follows the grid columns */
    border:solid 2px; 
    padding: 3px;
}
```

Then I have a `span` in my cshtml file, like this:

```
<span class="RoundedActivityCell" id="signalRAsxActivity-#:ViewUnitContract.ConveyanceId #">
    #: ViewUnitContract.Status.StatusText#
</span>
```

I know how to apply certain css properties like border-color etc. using jquery, but I was wondering if it's possible to remove the `class="RoundedActivityCell"` part from the html tag and set that using jquery instead?

I.e (Never mind the conveyanceId part, it's automatically generated and works the way it's supposed to :) ):

```
$('#signalRAsxActivity-' + conveyanceId).css.class('RoundedActivityCell');
```

Comment: how to identify the elements to which the class has to be added? is it to elements with id starting with `signalRAsxActivity`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ is a better place for simple questions like this, a single click at CSS and youll find a list of methods like addClass, removeClass etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
$('#signalRAsxActivity-' + conveyanceId).addClass("RoundedActivityCell")
```